# Swift mark enum elements with special keyword

Tags: ios, swift, enums, swift5

I need to know if Swift language has some way to achieve this feature of marking some elements of an enum. For instance, I have a set of properties in Swift enum and some of the properties are animatable while others are not. I want something like:

```
  public enum Property: String {

     case prop1,
     case prop2 @animatable,
     case prop3 @animatable,
     case prop4,
     case prop5 @animatable,
     ...
     ...
     ...
     case prop100

  }
```

And then in a function I can pass an argument such as:

```
func animate(_ prop: Property @animatable, startTime:CFTimeInterval, duration:CFTimeInterval) {


 }
```

So I pass a property which are elements of enum that are only animatable, not others. Is there a clean way to achieve something like this in Swift language (Swift 5)?

Comment: If you are referring to something like java annotations then the answer is no.

Comment: Create two enumerations

Comment: I can always create two enumerations, but was just wondering what is the cleanest way in Swift